# Does getNodeByText() search entire TreeView, for a match or current children under root?

Tags: javascript, asp.net, user-controls, telerik

When you are using the clientside javascript for a TreeView, there is a lot of information which i am unsure.  I dont have a sample to test with, but i was wondering if the getNodeByText will recursively search for the first occurance, or just search the children under the selected node.

Some documentation is located at http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/treeview-client-objects-radtreeview.html but it doesnt answer my specific question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my experience, every `Node` function only affects 1 Level at the time.

So this code would only affect the first level of nodes (A `Node` at the root of the `TreeView`):

```
var firstLevelNode = yourTreeView.getNodeByText('someText');
```

then you can call this fonction on any `Node`, so:

```
var secondLevelNode = firstLevelNode.getNodeByText('someOtherText');
```

You see? If you want to search for underlying children nodes, you must iterate for every root `Node`, and if you're looking for a 3rd level `Node`, you have to iterate thru every 2nd level `Node`, and so on...

Comment: Thanks for the info.  It has definately confirmed that i would have to write a small DFS or BFS to traverse the tree structure.  I wasnt sure if there were options for doing things like scanning the entire tree for matches etc.  Thanks a lot.